# weird behavior in pattern-matching and condition

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, conditional, condition

I'm confused by the following three different results involving pattern matching and condition.

```
aa[p]/(2 bb[p]) /. {((f_ /; (D[f, kk] == 0))/bb[kk_]) :> kk}
--> p
```

```
aa[p]/(2 bb[p]) /. {(f_/bb[kk_]) /; (D[f, kk] == 0) :> kk}
--> p aa[p]
```

```
aa[p]/(2 bb[p]) /. {(f_/bb[kk_]) /; (D[f, kk] == 0) :> cc[kk]}

--> aa[p] cc[p]
```

Intuitively I expect the first result, where one first check if the factor besides `bb[p]` depends on `p`, and if it doesn't, then extract the argument `p`.

However, I have completely no idea how the second and the third results arise (where from 1st to the 2nd the location of the condition is changed). Moreover, in the 2nd `kk` is matched with `p aa[p]`, why on earth in the 3rd `cc[kk]` spits out NOT `cc[p aa[p]]`, but instead a product `aa[p] cc[p]`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at (especially: Print[...]):

```
aa[p]/(2 bb[p]) /. {((f_ /; (Print[{f, kk, D[f, kk]}]; D[f, kk] == 0))/
     bb[kk_]) :> kk}
```

[image: ![]

We see, that when f_ is checked, kk has not yet a value. And therefore, "D[f, kk]D[f, kk]" is zero and the pattern matches and "p" is returned.

For the second case, consider:

```
aa[p]/(2 bb[
     p]) /. {(f_/bb[kk_]) /; (Print[{f, kk, D[f, kk], D[f, kk] == 0}];
      D[f, kk] == 0) :> kk}
```

[image: ![]

Now 2 attempts for a match are done. The derivative in the first attempt is not zero and is discarded. Then f is matched against 1/2 (this time only part of the expression is matched, aa[p] is not matched and retained). The derivative is of course zero and p together with aa[p] is returned.

The third case is similar to the second case.